# $(k^s)^p$ generates $k^s$ over $k$ if $k$ is $F$-finite?

Tags: extension-field, positive-characteristic

I am puzzled with the following (apparently easy ?) question.
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, such that $[k:k^p]<\infty$ (in other words, $k$ is $F$-finite, with $F: k\rightarrow k$ the Frobenius morphism).

Denote $k^s$ the separable closure of $k$: I want to show that $(k^s)^p$ generates $k^s$ over $k$. To do so, considering $L/k$ a finite separable extension of degree $n$, I'd like to show that $L^p$ generates $L$ over $k$, i.e., that if 
$e_1$, ..., $e_n$ is a $k$-basis of $L$, then $e_1^p$, ..., $e_n^p$ is still a $k$-basis of $L$.
Writing $L=k(x)$ for some $x\in L$ and taking $e_1=1$, $e_2=x$, ..., $e_n=x^{n-1}$, this is equivalent to showing that $1$, $x^p$, ..., $x^{p(n-1)}$ remains free over $k$.

EDIT: By analyzing the dimensions, assuming that the family $1$, $x^p$, ..., $x^{p(n-1)}$ is not free over $k$ would imply that $n$ is divisible by some $p^m$ (with $p^m$ the degree of the finite radical extension $L/k(x^p)$). If $n$ is prime to $p$ then we're fine.

EDIT2: In fact, the extension $L/k(x^p)$ is necessarily trivial. 
As $L/k$ is separable, then $L/k(x^p)$ is also separable (the minimal polynomial of any element of $L$ over $k(x^p)$ divides its minimal polynomial over $k$, hence has distinct roots): then $L/k(x^p)$ is trivial, for it's also radical. Thanks MooS for pointing it out.

So we didn't need the condition $[k:k^p]<\infty$.

Comment: Actually $k(a^p)=k(a)$ is a defining condition of $a$ being separable over $k$. In particular $k((k^s)^p)=k^s$ follows.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out ! And sorry for the stupid question :)